# How to read and store multiple user inputs in a variable while using appendChild

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been attempting to read multiple user input fields and storing them in a variable so that I can take what they inputted and work with it in a separate function. Unfortunately, I can't get the input to be read at all, anytime I try to reference it using .getElementByID, I always get that it is NULL.

The problem space I am trying to solve is that the user will be prompted to provide me a number of names of people they want to split a bill with. If they enter 5, then 5 text prompts are displayed asking them to give me the name of each person. I want to be able to read the 5 names and store them in an array or variable so that I can use these names later in other functions. I am at a loss in how to read and store the names and after looking online at many different solutions, I haven't been able to solve it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Attaching the two main components of the code below.

```js
function addFields() {
  // Number of inputs to create
  var number = document.getElementById("member").value;
  // Container <div> where dynamic content will be placed
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  // Clear previous contents of the container
  while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
    container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
  }
  for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    // Append a node with a random text
    container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Member " + (i + 1)));
    // Create an <input> element, set its type and name attributes
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "text";
    input.name = "member" + i;
    container.appendChild(input);
    // Append a line break 
    container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
  }
  var results = document.getElementById("input").value;
  alert(results);
}
```

```html
<!-- Start of Start Step 1 Splitting Start page -->
<div data-role="page" id="splitting_start">

  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Step 1: Enter Names of Patrons</h1>
  </div>
  <!-- /header -->

  <div data-role="content">

    <h3><u>Please enter names of patrons below:</h3></u>
      <input type="text" id="member" name="member" value="">Number of members: (max. 10)<br />
      <a href="#" id="filldetails" onclick="addFields()">Fill Details</a>
      <div id="container" />

  </div>
  <!-- /content -->

  <div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li> <a href="#homepage" data-icon="arrow-l" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">Go back to Homepage</a>
        <!--<li> <a href="#map" data-icon="info">What is this step?</a>-->
        <li> <a href="#splitting_items" data-icon="arrow-r" data-transition="slide">Go to Step 2: Enter Items </a>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div data-role="footer">
    <h5><i>Seven-Ten: The Easy Way To Split </h5></i>
  </div>
  <!-- /footer -->

</div>
<!-- /page -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to put all the inputs in a form, put a id in that form and read the form data with the elements property of a form element

Here you have a example:

```js
document.querySelector("#test").appendChild(document.createElement("input"));
document.querySelector("#test").appendChild(document.createElement("input"));
document.querySelector("#test").appendChild(document.createElement("input"));
function showFormValues() {
  let inputs = document.querySelector("#test").elements;
  var values = ""
  for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    // Disable all form controls
    values += inputs[i].value;
  }
document.querySelector("#resultTest").value = values
}
```

```html
<form id="test">
</form>
<input readonly placeholder="result" id="resultTest"/>
<button onclick="showFormValues()" > test</button>
```